# File with special character after upload to Centos 7 become different name

Tags: php, character-encoding, centos7, urlencode

I have a file name **corazón.mp3**, after upload to centos 7 using php it save in database **corazÃ³n.mp3** , I tried to access the directory via browser and I saw **coraz¨®n.mp3**, after I click on the file link, the browser link are **coraz%a8%aen.mp3**.

How can I convert from **corazón.mp3** to **coraz%a8%aen.mp3** in php? I have tried using UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 but I can't get **coraz%a8%aen.mp3**.

Comment: coraz%a8%aen.mp3 is urlencoded

Comment: Hi, if I urlencode corazón.mp3, I got coraz%C3%B3n.mp3 which can't get the file.

Comment: You have to make sure your [entire stack is using UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), if you want accented characters to work as you expect.